# Effect of filter ripple on OFDM

Tags: digital-communications

OFDM is a multi carrier signal divided in frequency domain into orthogonal subcarriers, where each subcarriers carries an information symbol.So the EVM per  subcarrier expresses the quality of the signal within that subcarrier bandwidth

If an OFDM signal at RF goes through a band pass filter that has some amplitude ripples, what is the effect of these ripples on the EVM of the subcarriers? Would the effect be the same like in a single carrier signal?

Comment: what is the coding of the single carrier signal?

Comment: The article "EVM Degradation in LTE Systems by RF Filtering" can help you. https://www.kaelus.com/uploads/Kaelus/6a/6aee5568-3cc2-4f27-ad6b-ffd121102b1b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ripple is slow (long in the frequency domain compared to the subcarriers), then the ripple can be an channel-dependent attenuation (or relative gain) which is easily ignored for phase-based (most modern) communication signals.  However, if it is fast (shorter in frequency than a subcarrier), then it will have a distorting affect on the received symbol and a more sophisticated equalizer may be needed.